# CMake - Property for IMPORT Library that would generate shor name for library in the linker cmd

Tags: c++, cmake

My Cmake C++ project builds on various platforms such as RHEL, AIX, Windows, HP-Unix.
I am linking my executable to IMPORTED Tuxedo library Targets which were not built by Cmake.

This works fine for all platforms except HP-Unix (acc compiler)

On all platforms the linker cmd links to **-L <path_to_tuxedo_libs> -ltux -lbuft -lfml** etc.,.

But on HP-UX the linker command looks like **-L <path_to_tuxedo_libs> -llibtux.sl -llibbuft.sl -llibfml.sl** etc.,.
And the linker error says "could not find the library" even though the library is present in the <path_to_tuxedo_libs>

I manually edited the link.txt generated by `cmake configure` and replaced **-llibtux.sl** to **-ltux** ..
With this change the build is successful

What Target property should be set in the IMPORTED TARGETS, so that Cmake generates the linker cmd with the short name (-ltux) instead of the full name (-llibtux.sl).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by using the below

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "HP-UX")
   set(CMAKE_EXTRA_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .sl)
endif()
```